# How to access normal arguments after subcommand arguments in python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a script in which I want to access an argument after I mention the subcommand and it's arguments. Like

```
Python helloworld.py details --name Zoro --sport hockey.
```

Here, details is the subcommand and --name is the subcommand argument where as --sport is a normal argument.

When I mention it like that, it is throwing error "unrecognized arguments: --sport"

However, if I mention this "--sport hockey" before "details" it is working fine.

Is it possible to access that argument?

Thanks.

Comment: No, at 'details' parsing passes to the subparser, and does not return to the main.

Comment: Ohh okay. Thanks.